# How to search environment variable with wild card in python like grep

Tags: python

let's say in my environment variable there is a keyword with value as below

```
search_env_keyword_mytest=test1234
```

and in unix shell if I run below command

```
search_env="search_env_keyword_"
find_match=`printenv | grep ${search_env}* `
then
echo $find_match will be search_env_keyword_mytest=test1234
```

how to achieve same effect in python
This is what I did, but it's not working.

```
pattern = "search_env_keyword_\\w+"
myPattern = re.compile(r'{linehead}'.format(linehead=pattern))
for a in os.environ:
        match = re.findall(myPattern, a)
```

it's not working, it's just printing `search_env_keyword_` instead `search_env_keyword_mytest=test1234`,  how can I print `search_env_keyword_mytest=test1234` in python as a outcome.

Answer (score 2):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) only returns the matched part of the string, not the entire string.  (This would be equivalent to `grep -o`.)  Since your regex should only match once per environment variable, you should just use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

Additionally, `os.environ` is a dictionary, so `a` is only the key.  If you also want to print the value, you need to add that manually.

```
myPattern = re.compile(r'search_env_keyword_\w+')
for key, val in os.environ.items():
    if myPattern.match(a):
        print(f'{key}={val}')
```

Answer (score 1):

interesting that your code example doesn't include a print statement but 'printing' is the bug ;)

In the code you did provide your problem is

```
for a in os.environ:
  do_something
```

In python, iterating over a dictionary is a list of keys. So if your env was
MYVAR=3
OTHERVAR=42

your list would be ['MYVAR', 'OTHERVAR']

if you wanted to get the whole thing you could do

```
for key, value in os.environ.items():
  line = key + "=" + value
```

Also, `re` is good for this- but you probably just need

```
if 'mysearchstring' in line:
  print(line)
```